# Android/iOS: How to dismiss a popup advertisement while automating an application using Appium & Robot Framework?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, robotframework, mobile-applications

[image]

Asking a solution to handle these kind of random Ad popups which comes up on any screen of the application.
If someone can help with threading solution using Python it would be great.

Comment: Have you talk to the developers to create a build that doesn't have ads? It usually is the case of a feature flag to be on or off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Appium Inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#the-inspector) to find the 'Close' button. This should give you an XPATH to work with. If it says 'Element Not Interact-able' in the properties pane then the trick I use is to get the Size and Location of the element to find the center and then `webDriver.Tap(x,y)`